# How do I use the DBISAM database in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, database-connection, dbisam

I am trying to connect to a DBISAM database. This database system is used mostly on Delphi. The table files are stored in a folder.

My question is: Is there a way to connect to these databases from vb.net? How should I go about doing that?

Comment: Seems to be a number of ADO.Net data providers out there. example: http://www.contextsoft.com/products/dbisamnet/downloads.php

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend purchasing the ODBC driver from [Elevatesoft](http://www.elevatesoft.com) for the version of DBISAM that you are using, and connect via ODBC.